# how to split text under a tag using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I am attaching sample XML file below

```
<root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
<actors>
    <actor id="1">Christian Bale = Liam Neeson and Michael Caine</actor>
</actors>
<foo:singers>
    <foo:singer id="4">Tom Waits=B.B. King and Ray Charles</foo:singer>
</foo:singers>
```

I want a XPath which can extract the text only "Liam Neeson" from the 'actor' tag. By using regular expressions.

I have written a xpath like
"//actor[1]/text()" and it is giving the output as
"Christian Bale = Liam Neeson and Michael Caine". But I want to extract only the "Liam Neeson" part.

Comment: use programming language

Comment: I am not running it under any programming language.

Comment: if so - you should deal at least with XPath 2.0

Comment: I want to do it by the regular expression

Comment: Regex in XPath requires XPath 2.0.  Is XPath 2.0 acceptable to you?

Comment: yes for sure, Xpath 2.0 is acceptable for me